# copy from psv file to excel file for multiple columns

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing

My PSV file looks like

```
Column1|Column2|Column3
Web_Value_in_file|123|OLA
Tab_Value_out_file|453|OLA
```

Source & target columns are different.
I want to cut the value from column1 to multiple columns in target by _ delimiter.
I want output file to be like in excel(.xlsx)

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
Web     In      123
Tab     Out     453
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/572177/edit) your post to include more information on the problem you are facing. You mentioned <tag>shell-script</tag> in the tags; does this have to be implemented purely in the shell, or can you use external programs like `awk`? Is the output file space- or tab-separated? Can you show us what you already tried, and where you faced problems?

Comment: Welcome! I posted an answer but I see that your expected output difers of the input. Why are the numeric values in the input in column 2 but in the output in column 3? How does `Web_Value_in_file` become  `Web`, and where do `In` and `out` come from?

Comment: Can you _explain_ the transformation of the data? Please update your question rather than answering in comments.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
column -s '|' -t file
```

Assuming no embedded pipe characters in any of the fields. For parsing of generic CSV data, use [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 1):

With a suitably recent version of [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html)

```
$ ~/src/miller/c/mlr --csvlite --ifs '|' --ofs tab put '
    x = splitnv($Column1,"_"); $Column3 = $Column2; $Column2 = capitalize(x[3]); $Column1 = x[1]
  ' then cat file.psv
Column1 Column2 Column3
Web     In      123
Tab     Out     453
```

With older versions of Miller you may not be able to use the `capitalize` function - you can either live with the lower-case `in`/`out` or convert to all upper-case `IN`/`OUT` by replacing `capitalize` with `toupper`.